# How to create a index for a ORDER BY?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

Here is my business report, and I only need to create a index for ORDER BY.
However, the group by is based on the SUM of amount and cost from different table, so how can I create the index?

```
     SELECT 
     TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID,CONSULTANT.EMP_NAME, 
     SUM(SERVICES_PERFORMED.SP_AMOUNT * SERVICE.SER_COST) AS TotalCost

     FROM SERVICES_PERFORMED,TECHNICAL,CONSULTANT,SERVICE

     WHERE TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = SERVICES_PERFORMED.TEMPLOYEE_ID AND
     TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID = CONSULTANT.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
     SERVICES_PERFORMED.SERVICE_ID = SERVICE.SERVICE_ID

     GROUP BY TECHNICAL.TEMPLOYEE_ID,CONSULTANT.EMP_NAME
     ORDER BY TotalCost DESC;
```

And here is the query that I thought about:

```
CREATE INDEX TCINDX ON  SERVICES_PERFORMED,SERVICE(TotalCost);
```

But it is incorrect.

Comment: You could only do such a thing through a table or a materialized view, Once you use group by the original table row structures are irrelevant and indexes on those tables would be ignored for ordering the calculated column. So you would need to persist the derived table, then place an index on that. I think you should concenrate on the joins and the group by, not on the final order by. Have you looked at an explain plan?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? How is having an index related to ORDER BY going to help? An index is used for retrieving rows from a stored table, not for ordering. Perhaps you think if you have an index, rows will be stored in index order? They won't. For a stored table, you could create an "index-organized table" where rows are, in fact, stored in index order, so ordering may be faster. So - not only would you need a materialized view (see Used_By_Already's answer), it would need to be an index-organized materialized view. Make sure you understand the consequences if you go that route.

Comment: Yes, I have all those indexes except the order by, since my professor's pdf stated that Oracle only support indexes on ORDER BY but not GROUP BY and I'm using Oracle so I just didn't bother to create index for it.

Comment: I just followed My professor's notes, it stated the rules for using indexes:   1. Create index for search columns frequently in WHERE clauses of SQL commands,which I already created and 2. Create index in SQL commands with columns in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but because I'm using Oracle , so I didn't bother to create for GROUP BY. I just wanted to know is it possible to create index for ORDER BY in my situation or I don't need to bother that either?

Comment: I am sure your professor's note didn't mean to cover the case of an aggregate query, where you `ORDER BY` the values of an aggregate function (such as `COUNT(...)` or `SUM(...)`). The notes refer specifically to COLUMNS in ORDER BY clauses - not other expressions. You can't create an index on the result of an aggregate function on a table.

Comment: He didn't really explain that situation in the notes, only the sample one for ORDER BY. I will leave that alone then. Thanks.